# Creating charts and graphs images with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: charts, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

I'm working on a project using .NET Core 3.1 as a back-end API for my solution and want to generate graphs/charts images to my reports. My API is already capable of generate PDF reports, but i can't find solutions for the chart problem. I need to generate bar and pie charts, save as images and have them available to my application.

The question is: there is some library, tool, extension or plugin available to generate Charts (bar charts, pie charts, etc) and save as image in .NET Core 3.1 ?

Thank you very much for read this far.